# Separate rows by matching two columns in similar pattern

Tags: r, tidyverse

i have data like

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("P,Q","X,Y"), B = c("P1,Q1",""), C = c("P2,Q2","X2,Y2"))
```

i am looking for output like

```
output <- data.frame(A = c("P","Q","X","Y"), B = c("P1","Q1","",""), C = c("P2","Q2","X2","Y2"))
```

i tried using separate_rows like mentioned below but it is not matching the strings seperated by comma.

```
separate_rows(df1, A, sep=",") %>%
  separate_rows(B) %>%
  separate_rows(C)
```

Answer (score 2):

you simply have to do :

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df1, A, B, C, convert = TRUE)
```

Output :

```
  A  B  C
1 P P1 P2
2 Q Q1 Q2
```

**Edit if you have `NA` and empty strings :**

```
data:
df1 <- data.frame(A = c("P,Q","X,Y"), B = c("P1,Q1",""), C = 
c("P2,Q2","X2,Y2"))


Code:

df1 <- data.frame(lapply(df1, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1[df1 == ""] <- "0,0"
df1 <- separate_rows(df1, A, B, C, convert = TRUE)
df1[df1 == "0"] <- ""
```

Output :

```
  A  B  C
1 P P1 P2
2 Q Q1 Q2
3 X    X2
4 Y    Y2
```

Comment: just another complexity, getting this error "Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements." may be i have some blank cells as well. what to do in such cases?

Comment: Sorry your first example didn't have ``NA``, I'll try to update it soon.

Comment: I edited my answer, this is not really pretty but I would do it this way since  this is simple. It seems like the ``separate_rows()`` function doesn't have inbuild arguments to work with ``NA``.

Answer (score 2):

I like `splitstackshape` package for such operations,

```
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(df1, splitCols = names(df1), sep = ',', direction = 'long')
#   A  B  C
#1: P P1 P2
#2: Q Q1 Q2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `base R` with `strsplit`

```
data.frame(lapply(df1, function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), ",")[[1]]))
#   A  B  C
#1 P P1 P2
#2 Q Q1 Q2
```

---

Or with `scan`

```
data.frame(lapply(df1, function(x) 
     scan(text = as.character(x), what = "", sep=",", quiet = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Gainz's answer, `separate_rows(df1, A, B, C, convert = T)` works really well.

However, if you do have blank cells in the dataframe then it does become harder to use, since it will give you an error about all the columns not having the same number of rows.

I suggest using a column that you know will have no blank values. Let's assume it is column A.

I would first then convert the dataframe to a tibble, and all factor columns to character columns. Then I would replace the blank cells with a string with the correct number of commas. Then `separate_rows()` should be able to work correctly.

Then the code will look as follows:

```r
df1_tibble <- df1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)

df1_clean <- df1_tibble %>% 
  mutate(count = str_count(A, ",") + 1) %>% 
  mutate(temp_str = map_chr(count, ~ rep("", .x) %>% paste0(collapse = ","))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(B, C), funs(ifelse(str_length(.) == 0, temp_str, .))) %>% 
  select(A, B, C)

df1_clean
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   A     B     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 P,Q   P1,Q1 P2,Q2
#> 2 X,Y   ,     X2,Y2

df1_clean %>% separate_rows(A, B, C)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   A     B     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 P     P1    P2   
#> 2 Q     Q1    Q2   
#> 3 X     ""    X2   
#> 4 Y     ""    Y2
```